# Swift 4 - Multi-line label chopped in AutoLayout UITableViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

Please find below my code to layout the UI programming of a UITableViewCell using AutoLayout:

```
// Profile Pic
profileView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
profileView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: commentImageSize + 4).isActive = true
profileView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: commentImageSize + 4).isActive = true
profileView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: borderSize).isActive = true
profileView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: borderSize).isActive = true

profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: commentImageSize).isActive = true
profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: commentImageSize).isActive = true
profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileView.topAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
profileImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileView.leadingAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true

// Time Ago Label
timeAgoLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
timeAgoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
timeAgoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
timeAgoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -borderSize).isActive = true

// Username Label
usernameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
usernameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileView.trailingAnchor, constant: borderSize).isActive = true
usernameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: timeAgoLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -borderSize).isActive = true
// *****
// (Not work)
// usernameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileView.topAnchor).isActive = true
// (Work)
usernameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: borderSize).isActive = true
// *****

// Comment Label
commentLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
commentLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
commentLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -borderSize).isActive = true
commentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
commentLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -borderSize).isActive = true
```

---

**This is what I would like to achieve:**
[image: Username Label stick to contentView]

**Before achieve my target, I tried another implementation. The implementation is as following:**

```
usernameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileView.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

However, by unknown reason, the multiple line comment label was tripped if using this implementation.
[image: Username Label stick to Profile Pic]

**After I use the following code, things work perfectly:**

```
usernameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: borderSize).isActive = true
```

Both lines of codes should have the same effect in my expectation. I would like to know why my original implmentation does not work as expected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know why my original implmentation does not work as
>   expected.

This code

```
usernameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileView.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

means that you are aligning your `usernameLabel`'s top to the top of `profileView`, which I believe you also know.

And this code:

```
usernameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: borderSize).isActive = true
```

means you are putting constraint to the cell or specifically cell's `contentView`.

Now, what you will need to make your multiline `UILabel` fit in a cell properly is to give it a **constraint to top and bottom** of its superview. It's like using a `UIScrollView`, you need proper constraints to each sides.

Again, in your first code, you're basically missing an important constraint which is constraint to the superview top. You can experiment things on Storyboard / Interface Builder as you wish.

Comment: Since I have a constraint on `profileView` which constraint to the top of its superview already, if I align `usernameLabel`'s top to the top of `profileView`, shouldn't it imply there is an constraint to `usernameLabel`  top which provide a top constraint for the multiline label?

Comment: You're correct, if all vertical constraints are if connected and imply that they are pushing the superview top and bottom, then the multiline label should be placed there properly. However, using `lessThanOrEqualTo` or `greaterThanOrEqualTo` might not help, try to replace that with just `equalTo`.